# Stripe Payments API

Tags: api, stripe-payments, secret-key, neto

I was hoping someone may know the answer to this.  I am integrating stripe payments into a new system we have started using.  We already have stripe connected to our webstore (managed by Neto/Maropost) for payments but want to have a 2nd connection to our new warehousing program (cin 7)to be able to invoice clients directly from there when applicable.
I have a question about API as I am really wary about breaking current connections we have in place.

I need the secret key as per the picture below:
[image]

If I click on reveal live key I get the following warning:

[image]

I am concerned if I click on it it will break my connections already set up.  Can someone please help me to confirm or deny this and put me out of my stressed misery?

I am self taught on all of this so always wary of breaking things before checking with those in the know.

Thanks for any help you can provide!!

Answer (score 0):

> I am concerned if I click on it it will break my connections already set up.

If your API key is being used by other plugins, then rolling it will break the other integrations that are using the older API key as that key would be invalidated.

You can copy the older API key if you can access the raw key from the other plugin or you can create a "restricted access key" from your Stripe Dashboard, giving it all the permissions your new plugin requires and share it with the new plugin.

If you are integrating to a new "Platform" and connecting to that using Stripe Connect, those platforms typically don't need your API keys, they use Stripe Connect functionality to make requests on your account.